# Aligning dataset columns in C

Tags: c, arrays, excel, alignment

I have a dataset of two groups: Red and Green, and I want to compare the difference between ratios, but they have to be aligned first.

Original File ( First few rows of 200,000 entries)

```
A   B       C       D
Red Ratio   Green   Ratio
1   0.35    1   0.21
2   0.45    2   0.235
3   0.45    3   0.154
4   0.235   4   0.156
6   0.156   5   0.146
7   0.668   6   0.154
8   0.44    7   0.148
9   0.446   8   0.148
10  0.354   9   0.199
11  0.154   10  0.143
12  0.49    12  0.148
```

After using the code, the values are aligned and the "extras" are delete, and the columns are shifted up.

```
A   B   C   D
Red Ratio   Green   Ratio
1   0.35    1   0.21
2   0.45    2   0.235
3   0.45    3   0.154
4   0.235   4   0.156
6   0.156   6   0.154
7   0.668   7   0.148
8   0.44    8   0.148
9   0.446   9   0.199
10  0.354   10  0.143
12  0.49    12  0.148
15  0.146   15  0.87
17  0.113   17  0.113
19  0.44    19  0.448
```

This is the code I have so far: I am taking difference between A and C to check if they are 0, and adjusting them if they are not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int deletemove(char column, int row)
    {
            // This script would delete the positions mentioned in the arguments, and shift the other values up.
    }


int main(void)
{

    //Opening input file for read/write

    FILE *input;

    input=fopen("/full/path/file.xlsx", "r");

    if (input == NULL) {printf("error opening input file\n");}

    //Store the values from file into an array

    int colA[1024];
    int colC[1024];

    // read contents of columns A and C and store in an array
    int ai;
    for(ai=1; ai<1024; ai++)
            {       fseek(input,ai,SEEK_SET);
                    colA[ai]=fgetc(input);
            }
    int ci;
    for(ci=1; ci<1024; ci++)
            {       fseek(input,ci,SEEK_SET);
                    colC[ci]=fgetc(input);
            }

    //Take difference between value of Column A and C to check if they are identical.

    int j;
    char A,B;
    for (j = 1; j < 1024; j++)
            {
                    int check = colA[j] - colC[j];  // check difference between two values in a column
                    if (check > 0)
                            deletemove(A,j);  //delete values from column C and D
                    else if  (check < 0)
                            deletemove(B,j); // delete values from column A and B
            }


    fclose(input); // close files

}
```

I need help implementing a delete row/column function and reading the values in array.

Also, is storing 200,000 values in an array a feasible method?

Thanks.

Comment: regarding this line: `if (input == NULL) {printf("error opening input file\n");}`  also need to `exit()` the program, not continue the program as if the open were successful

Comment: the code really only needs to have the current values from each column (assuming that the `A` and `C` are in ascending order)
plus the current value(s) being saved/tested against.
I would suggest, as each pair is matched, that a line be appended to a new file that contains the matching values.   Then when finished matching, read the matched values to process/display

Comment: arrays of 1024 in size are unlikely to be able to hold all the matches with an input of 200,000 lines of input.

Comment: this code: `int check = colA[j] - colC[j];
                    if check > 0` is a bit confusing,  Suggest `if( colA[j] == colB[j] )`

Comment: If I were going to store some 200,000 entries (times  2) in memory, I would not place them on the stack.   If your sure of the `200,000` number, then I suggest placing them in the `file global` memory.  However, if not sure of the exact number of entries, I suggest using the `heap` and the `realloc()` function to create the needed storage area.

Comment: do not use tabs for indenting, suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.  1) each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set for the individual preferences.  2) 4 spaces is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `int check = colA[j] - colC[j]  if check > 0`   They do not compile due to incorrect syntax.  Suggest: `int check = colA[j] - colC[j];  if( check > 0 )`  Note the addition of the semicolon and the parens.

Comment: this line: `fseek(input,ai,SEEK_SET);` will not set the file pointer to the desired location (`ai` is used as a byte counter in `fseek()` and what you really want is a line counter.)  Suggest read the whole line, for instance by using `fgets()`  then parse the line for the two desired fields, for instance by `strtok()`

Comment: the posted code does not compile, please post the actual code

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions and tips, user! I have also updated my code and tried to compile. I am currently reading and learning about the heap/realloc() and the other functions you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

> is storing 200,000 values in an array a feasible method?

Yes, as long as you don't put those arrays on the stack. Declaring a variable inside a function puts the variable on the stack<sup>(1)</sup>. Contemporary (year 2016) desktops typically limit the stack size to a few megabytes, whereas the main memory is a few gigabytes.

So it's best to put large arrays into main memory. This can be done in a variety of ways:

- use a global array, i.e. declare the array outside of any function
- use a static array, i.e. declare the array with the `static` keyword
- use a dynamically allocated array, i.e. use `malloc` to allocate the array

(You could also use a linked list. A linked list has the advantage that it can grow as needed; you don't need to know the space requirements in advance.)

In your case, I would store the ratios in the arrays at the index given by the red/green value. Assuming that ratios are always positive numbers, I would initialize all of the entries in the arrays with `-1.0`. Then, as you read the file store the ratios at the proper locations in the two arrays. For example, when you read the line

```
6   0.156   5   0.146
```

store `0.156` at index `6` in the red array, and store `0.146` at index `5` in the green array.

When all the values have been read from the file, you can simply scan the two arrays, and print the values where both arrays have a non-negative value.

(1) <sub>Ignoring oddball systems (e.g. small embedded systems) that don't have a normal stack.</sub>